# To be someone's priority

Tags: grammar

Can someone be your **priority**, when talking about having all your availability for that person? and can I omit (it) in the sentence below and just write **"will be fine"**? Feel free to add any corrections to my text.

> Hello Dr. Robert Frey, how are you doing today?  My name is Maria. I
>   am assisting Ms. Andrade on her trip to NY.  She is looking forward to
>   having these appointments with you. She will be in NY for a week from
>   May 7th till May 14th. She will have an event every night of the week,
>   but aside from that **you are her priority**, so whenever you can have
>   the appointment with her **will be fine**, you are her first choice.
>   As she requests, the first appointment would be the longest, around 2
>   hours, and the second could be shorter, around half an hour would be
>   fine.  Thank you a lot for your time! My best regards, Maria.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a simple manner, it represents you are Spending very Important time and detail in your life for them to take care of them or watch over them. In the text you included, it represents "She is your "priority" (She is your most important appointee, Take care of her First)

Comment: I read it more as ms Andrade saying that whenever Dr Robert Frey could fit her in for an appointment, she would move everything else around it. Not that she wanted to have priority over other patients.